# Laravel + Vue JS Blank Page on vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I got an issue when I tried using npm run watch.
after that, all Vue components are not loaded and I see blank data on the Vue component.

first the scripts in package.json looks like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

and I got an issue with not recognizing flag: --hide-modules .

after that i removes unrecognized flags and get this working script:

```
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js   --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

Also i changes the webpack.mix.js(add .vue()):
From:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

To:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and after that the cmd npm run watch working fine!
But now I get an issue with blank Vue components.
When I just bring back the file: public/js/app.js to the old file all works well.
But I can't modify this Laravel app.

[image: Example Image Explain The Source Code Vue Component Blank Page]

Please help me find the solution

Comment: What version of laravel you are using?

Comment: I am using Laravel Version:  6.17

Comment: Did you sort this?